# Datagrid with Autocomplete combobox - again

Tags: c#, wpf, datagridcomboboxcolumn, datagridtemplatecolumn

I understand this has been asked several times but I am unable to find a toolkit that allows for a combobox **in a WPF DataGrid** that allows to filter and autocomplete, none of the questions provide any solution that I was able to make work.
The behavior I need in my combobox column is:

- Pressing on drop down of the cell will show all objects in the ItemSource.
- As soon as you press on the "text box" portion of the combobox it would filter the drop down as  you enter/delete text and depending on the text in the combobox.
- Entering something invalid would show "not found" in the drop down. Pressing out or losing focus would just retain the last valid item in that combobox.

I have tried several options that I couldnt either get to work **with a datagrid** or they simply did not have the requirements above. Examples are:

1. DotNetProjects.WpfToolkit
2. Syncfusion.ComboBoxAdv

I have created a simple test application to test several options. My models are a Fruit and Vegetable object with just one property (Name). I have a Customer object that has a name and item (fruit or vegetable).
***Models***

```
public class Vegetable : IsFruitOrVegetable, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string name;

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return name;
        }
        set
        {
            name = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }

    public Vegetable()
    {

    }

    public Vegetable(string _Name)
    {
        this.Name = _Name;
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void RaisePropertyChanged(string PropertyName)
    {
        var property = PropertyChanged;
        if (property != null)
            property(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName));
    }
}

public class Fruit: IsFruitOrVegetable, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string name;

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return name;
        }
        set
        {
            name = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }

    public Fruit()
    {

    }

    public Fruit(string _Name)
    {
        this.Name = _Name;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void RaisePropertyChanged(string PropertyName)
    {
        var property = PropertyChanged;
        if (property != null)
            property(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName));
    }

}

public class Customer : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private string name;

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return name;
        }
        set
        {
            name = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }

    private IsFruitOrVegetable item;

    public IsFruitOrVegetable Item
    {
        get
        {
            return item;
        }
        set
        {
            item = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Item");
        }
    }

    private int totalQuantity;

    public int TotalQuantity
    {
        get
        {
            return totalQuantity;
        }
        set
        {
            totalQuantity = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("TotalQuantity");
        }
    }

    public Customer()
    {

    }

    public Customer(string _Name)
    {
        this.Name = _Name;
        Item = null;
        TotalQuantity = 1;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void RaisePropertyChanged(string PropertyName)
    {
        var property = PropertyChanged;
        if (property != null)
            property(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName));
    }
}
```

My viewmodel consists of a list of my customers (CustomersList) and itemsList (list of items for fruits and vegetables).

```
public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<Customer> customersList;

    public ObservableCollection<Customer> CustomersList
    {
        get
        {
            return customersList;
        }
        set
        {
            customersList1 = value;
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<IsFruitOrVegetable> itemsList;

    public ObservableCollection<IsFruitOrVegetable> ItemsList
    {
        get
        {
            return itemsList;
        }
        set
        {
            itemsList = value;
        }
    }

    private IsFruitOrVegetable itemOption;

    public IsFruitOrVegetable ItemOption
    {
        get
        {
            return itemOption;
        }
        set
        {
            itemOption = value;
        }
    }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        ItemsList = new ObservableCollection<IsFruitOrVegetable>();
        ItemsList.Add(new Fruit("Apple"));
        ItemsList.Add(new Fruit("Banana"));
        ItemsList.Add(new Fruit("Avocado"));
        ItemsList.Add(new Fruit("Blueberries"));

        ItemsList.Add(new Vegetable("Broccoli"));
        ItemsList.Add(new Vegetable("Cabbage"));
        ItemsList.Add(new Vegetable("Carrot"));
        ItemsList.Add(new Vegetable("Cauliflower"));

        CustomersList = new ObservableCollection<Customer>();
        CustomersList.Add(new Customer("Bob"));
        CustomersList.Add(new Customer("Tony"));
        CustomersList.Add(new Customer("John"));

        CustomersList[0].Item = ItemsList[0];
        CustomersList[1].Item = ItemsList[1];
        CustomersList[2].Item = ItemsList[2];
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void RaisePropertyChanged(string PropertyName)
    {
        var property = PropertyChanged;
        if (property != null)
            property(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName));
    }
}
```

My view for:

```
        <Label Content="DEFAULT COMBOBOX" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="32" Margin="22,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="207"/>
    <ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="22,47,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" DisplayMemberPath="Name"
              SelectedValue="{Binding ItemOption, Source={StaticResource viewModel}, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
              ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsList,Source={StaticResource viewModel}}"/>

    <DataGrid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="291" Margin="22,90,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="207"
              ItemsSource="{Binding CustomersList,Source={StaticResource viewModel}}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Customer" Binding="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="*"/>
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Item" ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsList,Source={StaticResource viewModel}}" Width="*"
                                DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                                SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Item, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

I know alot of solutions implement a template column but I cant find a combobox that works with the intent I want to implement this. Can someone provide a super simple example that allows or point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

I have done something similar, try https://github.com/DamnjanMarkovic/WPFMedicalData.

Comment: just loaded the project, could you help me by telling me which view you implemented this?

Comment: When you start the program, several pages will have combo boxes integrated with filtering function. For example -page Program should have several of them.

Comment: I cant run the project, as soon as I run it says "XML file not loaded" and opens up the windows but everything is blank. Program seems broken with missing files or something but I am not seeing any filtered comboboxes.

Comment: Of course it does, I didn’t put XML with data in the github project. But never the less, you can see that some of the fields are combobox. You just follow the code and you should get the idea how it works. Everything you need is implemented.

Comment: I am in the program page and nothing is working. all the bindings are broken.

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour is very specific. If you do not find any ComboBoxes, that behave the correct way you always can create it by yourself.

One Way could be a ToggleButton in Combination with an Popup. For Reusability you also can put it into an UserControl

Here a very minimalistic example, how you could start creating the control by yourself (not functional and tested).

```
        <ToggleButton x:name="MyButton" />
    <Popup
        PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=MyButton}"
        Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=MyButton}">
        <Border
            BorderBrush="Black"
            BorderThickness="2"
            Background="White">
            <StackPanel>
                <!-- Some Other Controlls like an TextBox for searching the contents -->
                <!-- List View for displaying the ItemSource -->
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
    </Popup>
```

To impement it into a Datagrid i would Recomment the TemplateCollumn.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Header">
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <uc:CustomUserControl />
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
```

Note that for the ItemSource requires a relative source if it is not part of your items model.

```
ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}, Mode=FindAncestor}, Path=DataContext.YourItemSource}"
```